# Generate list of possible address for autocomplete box

Tags: c#, sql

```
I have table 
===========================  
Id   PlaceName     ParentId  
1     Australia      Null  
2     NSW              1  
3     Sa               1  
4     Ashfield         2  


How can I generate list like below using c#
=============================================
Australia
NSW, Australia
SA, Australia
Ashfield, NSW, Australia

I will appreciate for your help
```

Comment: There is no way of knowing if Ashfield is a city in NSW or SA. You need to provide Parent table as well.

Comment: There is parent id 2 for Ashfield which is an Id of NSW and the parent Id of NSW is 1 which is again an Id of Australia so gets Ashfield, NSW, Australia

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `RDBMS` support's `RECURSIVE CTE` then try this

**Schema setup & Sample data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE recursive_cte
  (
     Id        INT,
     PlaceName VARCHAR(50),
     ParentId  INT
  )

INSERT recursive_cte
VALUES (1,'Australia',NULL ),
       (2,'NSW',1 ),
       (3,'Sa',1 ),
       (4,'Ashfield',2 )
```

**Recursive CTE query:**

```sql
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Id,
                PlaceName,
                ParentId,
                Cast(PlaceName AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS Parent_name -- CAST is used to avoid type mismatch between anchor and recursive part
         FROM   recursive_cte rc
         WHERE  ParentId IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT rc.Id,
                rc.PlaceName,
                rc.ParentId,
                Cast(rc.PlaceName + ',' + Parent_name AS VARCHAR(8000))
         FROM   cte c
                INNER JOIN recursive_cte rc
                        ON c.id = rc.ParentId)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

**Result:**

```sql
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ Id ║ PlaceName ║ ParentId ║      Parent_name       ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Australia ║ NULL     ║ Australia              ║
║  2 ║ NSW       ║ 1        ║ NSW,Australia          ║
║  3 ║ Sa        ║ 1        ║ Sa,Australia           ║
║  4 ║ Ashfield  ║ 2        ║ Ashfield,NSW,Australia ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Nice! In C# you'd have to use Linq and DataTable but why not do it in sql.

Comment: @numbtongue  yes, `Recursive CTE` in SQL is introduced to handle hierarchical data like above

Comment: Great ! Thank you so much. It really helped me a lot.